# Выбрать строки из базы данных с определенным ID

Tags: cursor, android, база-данных, sql

К примеру есть массив **`RoutesAndStations[23,56,78,198,321]`** выбранные из другой таблицы **Routes**. Как мне получить строки с **`id 23,56,78,198,321`** , из таблицы  **Stations**.

```
private void fullFreinds() {
        Stations = new ArrayList<String>();

        String[] colNames = new String[] {STATIONS_ID, STATION_NAME};

        Cursor frienCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAIME, colNames, null,
                                                        null, null, null, null);

        frienCursor.moveToFirst();
        if(!frienCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                String names = frienCursor.getString(1);
                Stations.add(names);
            } while (frienCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: Nstatio = " + Stations);
        frienCursor.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто добавьте параметр selection (третий argument метода query):

```
String selection = STATIONS_ID + " in (";
String delimiter = "";
for (long id: RoutesAndStations) {
  selection += delimiter + Long.toString(id);
  delimiter = ", ";
}
selection += ")";
Cursor frienCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAIME, colNames, selection,
                                                        null, null, null, null);
```

Код не проверял, но вроде бы должно работать.

Upd: _id нужно хранить в long, чтобы все правильно работало.

Comment: Получаю вот такой массив **itemClick: statio = [2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 23, 31, 34, 105, 106, 108, 110, 112, 114, 118]**

И ошибка E/SQLiteLog(8445): (1) near "5": syntax error

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "5": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, name FROM Stations WHERE _id= 2 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 23 31 34 105 106 108 110 112 114 118

Comment: @smalser, откуда у вас берется "WHERE id_="? Если вы используете мой код, то должно быть "WHERE _id in".

Comment: После добавления selection начинает ругаться на массив RoutesAndStations

**Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type String to int**

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо все работает 
только я поправил 

String selection = STATIONS_ID + " in (";
     String delimiter = "";
     for (String id: RoutesAndStations) {
       selection += delimiter + id;
       delimiter = ", ";
     }
     selection += ")";
     Cursor frienCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAIME, colNames, selection,
                                                             null, null, null, null);

Comment: Хорошо, что работает, но это не очень правильно. В документации сказано, что вызов cursor.getString(key), когда тип данных для key не String, может вернуть что угодно, в том числе бросить исключение -- поведение зависит от конкретной имплементации. Лучше измените тип RoutesAndStations на ArrayList<Long>, и читайте из базы с помощью Cursor.getLong.